# Validation in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, validation

I don't why when I submit a POST request with an invalid `numSeatAvailable`. No error is return. I don't know if I missed anything. Could anyone help me please?

This is my request Class

```java
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.sql.Date;

@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
public class RideRequest {

    private Date date;
    private Time time;
    private String destination;
    private String modelName;
    private int modelYear;

    @Min(value = 18, message = "Age should not be less than 18")
    @Max(value = 150, message = "Age should not be greater than 150")
    private int numSeatAvailable;

    private String rideIntro;
    private Long driverId;
    private Long rideId;
}
```

This is my controller

```java
@PostMapping("/createRide")
public String createRide(@Valid @RequestBody RideRequest rideRequest) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    rideService.createRide(rideRequest);
    return "created";
}
```

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file or pom.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you must return message, info when the DTO is not valid.

About validation, you have 3 ways:

(1) Add Hibernate validator dependency

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Then add annotations for validate bean (DTO: Data Transfer Object).

(2) Ah, have an easy way for you: Use `spring-boot-starter-validator` (it is also a derived of Hibernate validator with pre and auto configuration). See tutorial at
https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/ . I suggest you use this way.

(3) Use Java validation (standard library). Guide:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

Answer (score 0):

You can use javax.validation.constraints Library

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
```

Add your constraitns to your DTO Model
for example :

```
@NotNull(groups = ProductCreation.class,message = "fieldName.notSetted")
@NotBlank(groups = ProductUpdate.class,message = "fieldName.notSetted")
@Min(value=1, message="fieldName must be equal or greater than 0")
```

And you can make function for validation :

```
 private void checkIfReadyToSave(ClassDTO yourDTO) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<ClassDTO>> violations =
        validator.validate(yourDTO, groupCreation.class);
    if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
      Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
      Set<String> keys =
          violations.stream().map(ConstraintViolation::getMessage).collect(Collectors.toSet());
      body.put("errors", keys);
      throw new BeanValidationException(ErrorConstants.ClassDTO_MISSING_ERROR_MSG, body.toString());
    }
  }
```